# How to add new TextView to the MY LAYOUT

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have a `RelativeLayout` in my app. How to add a new `TextView` to the my layout?

I want to add a `TextView` programatically, when the `Activity` starts.

Now layout looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/common_background" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            tools:context=".News" >

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I need result:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/common_background" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            tools:context=".News" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text="Title" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text="Date" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
                android:text="Content" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My "News.java" code:

```
public class News extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.news);
    }
}
```

Comment: why not use a custom listview with textviews instead of scrollview.?

Comment: Do you want to fill a grid row by row with items programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all put an id to the RelativeLayout.

```
android:id="@+id/mylayout1"
```

Now, you can do it as,

```
TextView myText= new TextView(News.this);
    myText.setText("This is inside Relative layout");
    myText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    ((ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.mylayout1)).addView(myText);
```

But I'll suggest you to use Custom list view instead. Which is more flexible and we can have more control on it. Here is a nice tutorial- [Custom adapter](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)

Answer (score 1):

do something like that :-
make an object and then add it to parent layout.

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout2);

        // add text view
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("Dynamic Text!");

 tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        ll.addView(tv);
```

Here is a simple tutorial for it. visit this [link](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/10/android-programmatically-generate.html)